# AngularJS filtering on a formatted date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table generated with like so:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter: employeeSearch">
    <td>{{employee.lastName}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.hireDate | date: format : mediumDate}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.phone | phone}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.email}}</td>
</tr>
```

I'm using a text box to filter the table

```
<input type="text" id="employeeSearch" placeholder="Search employees" data-ng-model="employeeSearch" />
```

The dates are formatted like Jun 15, 2015 but since they're stored as a date object before getting formatted as a mediumDate I have to type 2015-06-15 to filter to that date. Is there some way to specify that I want my employeeSearch input to filter on displayed values instead of stored values?

I tried modifying the date object in my query function to no avail.

Comment: what does your `employeeSearch` filter look like

Comment: It's the <input> line above. It's just a text box and it's filtering any of the columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a method in controller

```
$scope.filter=function(obj){
 return match(obj.lastName) || match(obj.firstName) || (new Date($scope.employeeSearch)) == (new Date(obj.hireDate)) || match(obj.phone) || match(obj.email)
}
function match(value){
 return value.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.employeeSearch.toLowerCase()) > -1;
}
```

Add this method to view

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter: filter">
```

Comment: There's better ways to write that than a massive long line of code... ;-;

Comment: @Quill Please feel free to share :)

Comment: You can create a function to simplify those `$scope.employeeSearch` parts